# Does Angular routing work on LAMP server

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, angular

I am hosting my Angular 2 app on http://www.ixwebhosting.com/
They provide a traditional LAMP stack.

I have a route like this: www.mysite.com/myapp/item/:id and it works fine in my local ng serve environment.

The index.html page at www.mysite.com/my-app/ loads fine - but when I enter www.mysite.com/my-app/item/1 into the browser it fails. I suspect because the routing hits the web server first - and since the web server can't find an actual directory or file at that location it returns a 404. Is there a way to config an Apache server to work with Angular routing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just redirect all requests directed to a file that doesn't exist to index.html - something like WP does:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /my-app/
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Of course, this .htaccess file should be placed in "my-app" folder.

Comment: But my Angular app is in a directory www.mysite.com/my-app - so how would you rewrite the above?

Comment: Thanks, I have tried but it is still re-directing to the index.html of the root directory. Perhaps the last line needs to change as well? (RewriteRule . /index.html [L])

Comment: Thanks, actually the edited answer  did not work for me. But this did work: (RewriteRule . /my-app/index.html [L])

Comment: Did you put .htaccess in question in "my-app" folder, or root?

Comment: It's inside my-app

Comment: Well, I'm testing on XAMPP, and .htaccess in answer works as explained in answer. Anyway - the trick was to route all requests to angular app and let it do real routing.